# REST API for Quick Books desktop

Tags: quickbooks

Is there any REST API associated with Quick books Desktop ?
I am aware of Quickbooks SDK and one can build its requests via QBFC or QBXML.

However,I have set of hardcoded request xmls ,I was wondering is it possible to test these XMLs by sending directly to Quickbooks Desktop via tool like SOAPUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any REST API associated with Quick books Desktop

Yes, but it's deprecated. You can't build new apps for it -- only existing apps already using it are allowed to use it.

> However,I have set of hardcoded request xmls ,I was wondering is it possible to test these XMLs by sending directly to Quickbooks Desktop via tool like SOAPUI.

You could easily write your own little SOAP server that sits and listens for requests and runs them against QuickBooks if you wanted to. Or use the SDK Test+ tool included with the SDK and feed them to QuickBooks directly from files.